# Overlapping template partial specialization when wanting an "override" case: how to avoid the error?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm dealing with a pretty simple template struct that has an enum value set by whether its 2 template parameters are the same type or not.

```
template<typename T, typename U> struct is_same { enum { value = 0 }; };
template<typename T> struct is_same<T, T> { enum { value = 1 }; };
```

This is part of a library (Eigen), so I can't alter this design without breaking it.  When `value == 0`, a static assert aborts compilation.

So I have a special numerical templated class `SpecialCase` that can do ops with different specializations of itself.  So I set up an override like this:

```
template<typename T> struct SpecialCase { ... };

template<typename LT, typename RT> struct is_same<SpecialCase<LT>, SpecialCase<RT>> { enum { value = 1 }; };
```

However, this throws the error:

```
more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
```

Now, I understand why.  It's the case where `LT == RT`, which steps on the toes of `is_same<T, T>`.  What I don't know is how to keep my `SpecialCase` override and get rid of the error.  Is there a trick to get around this?

edit: To clarify, I need all cases where `LT != RT` to also be considered the same (have value 1).  Not just `LT == RT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a special case for SpecialCase where the arguments are the same:

```
template < typename T >
struct is_same < SpecialCase < T >, SpecialCase < T > >
{ enum { value = 1 }; };
```

That is more specific than each of the ambiguous candidates.

edit: Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T, typename U> struct is_same {
    enum { value = 0 };
};
template<typename T> struct is_same<T, T> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template<typename T> struct SpecialCase {  };

template < typename T >
struct is_same < SpecialCase < T >, SpecialCase < T > >
{
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template<typename LT, typename RT> struct is_same<SpecialCase<LT>, SpecialCase<RT> > {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

int main ( int, char** )
{
std::cout 
<< is_same < SpecialCase < int >, SpecialCase < int > >::value
<< is_same < SpecialCase < int >, SpecialCase < double > >::value
<< is_same < SpecialCase < int >,  double >::value
<< is_same < double, SpecialCase < int > >::value
<< is_same < double, double >::value
<< is_same < double, int >::value
<< std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I take it this doesn't compile for you? It works for me on all four cases <T1, T2>, < T, T >, < SpecialCase<T>, SpecialCase<T> >and < SpecialCase<T1>, SpecialCase<T2> >. I'm using gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Ok, this is strange. I'll post the whole code, which works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: http://liveworkspace.org/code/FiY2J, the output is 1001 and should be 1011

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you meant that it should be added to, not replace his attempt. +1, sorry for the downvote.

Comment: Well, my code can compile now, so it must be working.  I didn't know about this, neat trick.

Comment: @SethCarnegie My bad, I could have stated that clearer. I'm glad it worked out in the end.